# Java: Передача файла с использованием multipart/form-data

Tags: java, java-ee, form, веб-программирование, fileupload

Объясните пожалуйста что такое `multipart/form-data`.

В `web.xml` указывается:

```
<multipart-config>
   <file-size-threshold>...</file-size-threshold>
   <max-request-size>...</max-request-size>
   <max-file-size>...</max-file-size>
</multipart-config>
```

Прочитал документацию и не уверен, что понял все правильно.

Что означают и когда их указывать `file-size-threshold`, `max-request-size`, `max-file-size`?

Зависят они друг от друга или нет?

Если загрузить файл большего размера, чем указан в `web.xml`, как обеспечить проверку размера в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html

> Если загрузить файл большего размера, чем указан в web.xml, как
>   обеспечить проверку размера в этом случае?

Обрабатываете `catch` исключение `IllegalStateException`.

```
try {
   // обработка события загрузки файла
} catch(IllegalStateException ise) {
   // обработка попытки загрузить файл большего размере, чем указан в соответствующем параметре в web.xml
}
```

> Что означают и когда их указывать file-size-threshold,
>   max-request-size, max-file-size?
>
> Зависят они друг от друга или нет?

Нет, вроде же разные параметры.

`fileSizeThreshold` -- говорит, когда на диск временно сохранять файл

`MaxFileSize` -- максимальный размер файла для загрузки. Если размер больше - система посылает IllegalStateException, которое можно в блоке `catch` обработать.

`maxRequestSize` -- максимальный размер вообще всех файлов (данных) для загрузки. Видимо, когда разрешено выбрать много файлов и т.п.

Как написано, эти параметры не являются обязательными, указываются только если нужно для чего-то.

> Объясните пожалуйста что такое multipart/form-data.

А что конкретно не понятно?
Определяет способ кодирования данных формы при их отправке на сервер. (например, файлов). То есть, как бы правило для системы, что бы она понимала, как прочитать эту часть данных.
http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms

Comment: `Part part = request.getPart("parameter");`
`String fileName= extractFileName(part);`
`part.write(IMAGE_PATH + File.separator + fileName);`
Я загружаю файл большего размера, но все успешно проходит

Comment: @Fairkhan
Не видя кода трудно что-то сказать. Пробовали и как аннотацию, и как конфигурацию `web.xml`? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html

Comment: `getPart() throws  IOException, ServletException` я видимо не там IllegalStateException ловлю, и не пойму при вызове какого метода связанного с multipart/form-data ловить, нужен пример кода, я передаю картинку.

Comment: @Fairkhan
Исходя из примера, IllegalStateException может быть в ряду с FileNotFoundException
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

Comment: Я в web.xml написал один параметр `<max-file-size>4194304</max-file-size>` однако картинки размеров больше чем 4 Мб грузятся. Не пойму где логика тут

Comment: А если сделать `@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize=4194304)` перед `processRequest` методом - тоже не работает?

Comment: Использование аннотаций тоже никак не влияет

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848475/873481 -- может, можно попробовать...
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets016.htm#BABDGFJJ -- если сделать отдельно, как в примере, отдельным проектом - так пробовали, работает?